# Office 365 Outlook keeps prompting for password

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, office365

I added my work email(On Exchange 2016) to Office 365 Outlook and it keeps prompting me for my password. I have tried my email password, my Microsoft account password and i have tried signing in with my office 365 account login and nothing works. If i close the box and click on the Need Password at the bottom of outlook it will connect me back to Exchange without needing my password. It is hard to do much in outlook without it popping um multiple times.

Image of prompt here
https://afa.net/media/480883/annotation-2020-07-16-092933.png

Comment: Wait, so does it say that there is an issue with the password you place, or does it not recognize. I am a bit confused.

Comment: When i try to enter my password i just get the error "Your account or password is incorrect. If you don't know your password reset it now". It looks like it's wanting me to sign in to a Microsoft account but my work email is an Exchange account. My Microsoft password does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Similar issues?

[Password Prompt](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ac3c0fea-3a49-4542-81fe-70c12cc79642/password-prompt?forum=outlook)

[Outlook bypasses AutoDiscover and connects directly to Office 365 mailbox](https://www.gothamweb.com/portal/index.php/knowledgebase/8/Outlook-bypasses-AutoDiscover-and-connects-directly-to-Office-365-mailbox.html)

Please try the registry key ExcludeExplicitO365Endpoint and see if it works.